# Is it possible to reinitialize the graphics state in a pdf file?

Tags: c++, pdf

I want to create a program in c++ to add a simple image in the first page of a pdf file. I chose libqpdf as it rather simple to use. However I found out that there are some pdf files that when I add the image as the first object of the page content, the image appears correctly, but when I add the image as the last object of the content, the image appears upside-down and in the wrong position. I suspect that the CTM is modified and not restored as is expected.

Is it possible to reset the graphics state CTM matrix using a cm operation?

The code (still in a very early state) can be found here: https://github.com/parapente/qpdfImageEmbed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

"cm" always concatenates the matrix to the current matrix and there is no operator to set it.

Which is why most PDF creation involves lots of

```
q
...
Q
```

pairs to save and restore the graphics state (including the matrix).

If you need to add something to the end of the page stream, you could write a "q" command at the very beginning of the page stream, add a "Q" at the very end, end then add your operations.

Comment: I was almost certain the answer would be no, but the solution you gave would solve my problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Not having a "set matrix" command is one of the annoying features of PDF :-)

Comment: Does "q" also save a current path? I want to fill and stroke my path this way:  "... q f Q  S ", but it does not work :(  (yes, I know about "B").

Comment: Well, you already did the test so you know the answer :) No, the current clipping path is a part of the graphics state but the path you are building itself is not (the path your are building is an object, not a property of the current graphics environment...)